# Cant change name of colnames in text file using R

Tags: r

my text file  :

```
jack,28,25.2
smith,23,10.5
lena,49,11
leo,29,21.9
sara,38,44
ibra,23,11.5
Ayan,29,45
```

```r
sample <- read.table("sample.txt", sep = "|",  header=F)
colnames(sample) <- c("name","age","income")
```

i try to change name of col but i have error:

```
'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

Comment: Why are you using `sep="|"`, it appears to be comma-delimited. Your data looks to have three columns, check `ncol(sample)` to see if it is what you expect. I suspect it is `1` because you are reading it in wrong. (Set to `sep=","`, or frankly *just use* `read.csv("sample.txt", header=FALSE)`.)

Comment: Your text file uses `,` as a delimiter but when you read it in you specify `|` as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you should use `read.csv("sample.txt", header=FALSE)` or `read.csv("sample.txt",sep=",", header=FALSE)` .

Because of the use of `,` as seperator in your textfile.